# changing log file location for nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, server

I am trying out simple changes in nginx.conf file. I tried changing the location of error log from `/var/log/nginx/error.log` to `/path/to/directory/error.log`. But when I try restarting the nginx service, the service fails to startup and when I check its status, following log shows up.

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/path/to/directory/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

I tried changing ownership of the directory but still it fails. Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Ensure the folder's owner matches the nginx user.

Comment: the folder's owner matches the owner defined in nginx.conf file. @TanHongTat

Answer (score 0):

Your path directory is not owned by NGINX user which is  www-data so you need to run

chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/log/file

Comment: the default log file inside `/var/log/nginx/error.log` is owned by `nginx` user not `www-data`. I changed the ownership of `/path/to/directory/error.log` to `nginx` but still nothing changed.

Comment: nginx is not the user. your websuser in case of nginx is www-data